# SQL View timing out used by .NET Application

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a .NET Application using LINQ to SQL (ORM) to call a view which contains joins from multiple objects in different databases. The .NET Application times out calling this view, however our DBA runs the following statement:

```
sp_refreshview on the view and the subsequennt sql views
```

the application starts running again.

This application starts timing out again on the same view after close to 20 minutes. So our DBA has scheduled a job to run the above statement every 30 minutes. There has been no structural changes to the view and we are trying to figure why `sp_refreshview` fixes this problem and what could be the underlying issue that we could fix?

Comment: Does the view contain any inline functions? and how long does it take to execute when run directly without a layer such as .net? so through management studio etc...

Comment: view does not contain any inline functions. view only takes few milliseconds when directly run through .net or sql management studio when sp_refresh is done. if sp_refresh is not done, view still only runs within milliseconds from sql server but times out when run from .net

Comment: @user1490835, your last comment sounds exactly as the title of the article [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) by Erland Sommarskog that I pointed out in my answer a while ago. Have you read it and checked that the problem is different from what is discussed in that article?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, i did look at the article and nothing in there that we already don't know or tried. I have flicked it over to our DBA as well and no positive feedback from there. However i will award you the bounty anyways as this seems to be the most useful answer (every answer/comment was useful) but since the issue still remains, i won't mark it as answer.

Comment: Thank you @user1490835. Unfortunately, I don't have any other ideas. I'd try to confirm if there are two different execution plans - "slow" and fast. If yes, then see what you can do to prevent the server from generating the "slow" plan. If the plan is the same for the app and SSMS, then examine the app to figure out why sometimes the query is slow.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that `sp_refreshview` is fixing the issue is that the view is not schema-bound. SQLServer keeps metadata about the view to aid in execution, and since the view is not schema-bound the metadata becomes outdated as the base objects are updated (think DML statements). What `sp_refreshview` does is update that metadata for non-schema-bound views so they can run optimally. Take a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx) for `sp_refreshview`.

For some clarification on why this works, think about what a view is? A view is just a query. The metadata that is stored relates to that query.

Whenever you run a query, the server will figure out the most optimal way to run that query (called a plan), and that depends on the statistics of the tables used in the query. As the data in the tables change, the statistics for the tables will change, and so the plan can change. When you create a view (non-schema-bound), metadata around the optimal execution is stored (most likely the plan). Since a view is just a query, the plan can become outdated and `sp_refreshview` updates that metadata.

Comment: ok but the question is nothing is updated inside the view. The view has been the same for last 2 years. No DML Statement...nothing related to the view has been touched. We did look at the documentation before posting this question and nothing is making much sense at the moment except that it is working

Comment: The underlying data that comprises the view has not changed in 2 years? The view itself is not what is changing, it is the data in the tables that comprise the view that would be changing.

Comment: but how would that change the metadata around the view?

Comment: The problem is it still timeout if we update statistics and ignore view refreshing (sp_refreshview)
If what you are saying is correct, then update statistics will definitely optimize the execution plan thus tuning the view….however that's not the case

Comment: If you want a fix, you need to schema bind your view. Without that, you will need to run `sp_refreshview` periodically for optimum performance.

Comment: yes the question is still the same why? if what you are saying above is correct, then how come the update statistics wouldn't fix the issue? i understand that sp_refreshview is fixing the issue but don't clear understand why?

Comment: Updating statistics updates the tables statistics whereas `sp_refreshview` updates metadata that is used to generate a query plan for the view.

Comment: Please see my answer. This is related to the actual tables in your query defining your view. If you would share the query and any processing being done on the underlying tables, you will get a more definitive answer. Any changes to the underlying tables in the query will cause sp_refreshview to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `sp_refreshview` causes the server to remove the cached execution plan of your query from the cache. When you run the query after a call to `sp_refreshview` the new (better) execution plan is generated. This is why calling `sp_refreshview` helps. Apparently, updating statistics doesn't remove cached execution plans, that's why it doesn't help in your case.

There are some types of queries that can't have a good plan for all possible values of parameters, or your data may be significantly skewed.

If you add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to your query most likely you will not need to call `sp_refreshview` to make it work fast.

I don't know how to add this query hint when the query is generated by your ORM.

I recommend you to read an excellent article [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Comment: It's not working. Any other suggestions? Is there a way i can get hold of the sql inside the sp_Refreshview stored procedure?

Comment: @user1490835, I'd try to use SQL Profiler to see what queries are executed when `sp_refreshview` runs.

Comment: From what i know and read on Google and after chatting with our DBAs, SQL Server does not seem to create query plans for views.

Comment: @user1490835, of course, it doesn't create execution plans for views. It creates execution plans for the actual queries that access tables though views. My guess is that these execution plans become non-optimal after 20 minutes in your case. `sp_refreshview` would cause the server to remove all cached plans that were built for queries using the view. You should be able to achieve the same effect by not caching the plan in the first place with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`. ...

Comment: @user1490835, On the other hand, if you are saying that `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` doesn't help you, then my guess that `sp_refreshview` causes the server to remove the cached plans is wrong. Or the problem is not related to non-optimal plan. To confirm, I'd try to get an execution plan when the query runs fast, then execution plan when the same query runs slowly in 20 minutes and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Metadata is information about the tables used by the view. Statistics updates the information about the data. It might help to see your View definition. For example, having a select * in the view could really cause you problems. As a refresher, a view is just a statement until it is executed. If you are using tables that are always changing their structure or are dropped and re-added, you will need to be running sp_refreshview every time. If you want additional help, you will need to provide the query and any information on the underlying tables, like processes the refresh them. All of the above comments were within reason correct.